# radiobutton not setting value

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

I am in the process of making a text editing program but when I run this code
it doesnt work because on line 13, selecfont.get() isnt returning any value.
I dont know if it is something to do with the for loop but I cant fix it
I'm having a similar problem on another program.
Thanks

```
from tkinter import *
from os import listdir
from os import path
from threading import Thread

def open():
    print("open selected")

def save():
    print("save selected")

def fontchange():
    sheet.config(font = (str(selecfont.get())))
    print(selecfont.get())

fonts = ["Arial","Courier New","Times New Roman","Verdana",
"System","Impact","Fixedsys","corbel"]
master = Tk()
master.config(bg =  "#080d31")
master.title("Ed.co")

menubar = Menu(master,background = "#080d31")

filemenu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label = "open",command = open)
filemenu.add_command(label = "save",command = save)
menubar.add_cascade(label = "file",menu = filemenu)

settingsmenu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
fontmenu = Menu(settingsmenu,tearoff=0)
settingsmenu.add_cascade(label = "font",menu = fontmenu)
menubar.add_cascade(label = "settings",menu = settingsmenu)
for font in fonts:
        selecfont = StringVar()
        fontmenu.add_radiobutton(value = font,label = font,variable =       selecfont,command = fontchange)

sheet = Text(master,width = 71,height = 15,font = "corbel")
sheet.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan = 3)

master.config(menu = menubar)
master.mainloop()
```

Error message:

```
sheet.config(font = (str(selecfont.get())))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1319, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1310, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: font "" doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radiobuttons need to share a common variable, but you're creating a new variable for each radiobutton. You need to move the definition of `selecFont` outside of the loop:

```
selecFont = StringVar()
for font in fonts:
    ...
```

Comment: @user4475889: what other program? What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: just another program that i was writing.radiobuttons

Comment: on this other program the radiobuttons created in a for loop don't give a value to the variable. Also when I run the program, all of the radiobuttons are shown as selected.

Comment: folders = [d for d in listdir("C:/Users/Ed/Documents") if path.isdir(path.join("C:/Users/Ed/Documents", d))]
    selfolder = StringVar()
    for folder in folders:
        folderselect = Radiobutton(loadmaster,text = folder,variable = selfolder,value = folder,command = loadfile)
        folderselect.pack()

Comment: @user4475889: sorry, I can't help you on a program I can't see. However, radiobuttons must have a value, otherwise there's no point in having radiobuttons. They are designed to work as a set, each with a distinct value, and all sharing the same common variable.

Comment: ill ask another question when I can @Bryan Oakley

Comment: hi @user4475889, if the answer is useful to you consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the checkmark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.